# Tuple brackets '(' been converted to token when tokenizing tweets using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, tokenize

I am just getting started with Spark. Am trying to count the number of mentions for each token in tweets. To do this, I have created pair rdd with user_id and tweets, grouped by each user_id (so I have user as key and tweets as each user as a tuple for the values). Applied a tokenize function to the tweets and removed duplicate tokens for each user. I then mapped each token to 1 and reduced by key. Please see below for code:

```
    user_tweets.mapValues(lambda x: list(tok.tokenize(x))).mapValues(set).flatMap(lambda x: ((i, 1) for i in x[1])).reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)
```

I notice when I tokenize the tweets, the '(' and ')' for the tuples are created as separated tokens.

Original tweet:

> ('14241527',
>   ('RT @BernieSanders: "I will certainly look into it." - @HillaryClinton > \n\nVoters deserve to know what she told Wall Street and Big Pharma beh…',
>     'RT @CamaraNjeri: Bernie ❤️.))

Tokenized Tweet:

> ('14241527',   ['(',    "'",    'rt',    '@berniesanders',    ':',
>   '"',    'i',    'will',    'certainly',    'look',    'into',    'it',
>   '.',    '"',    '-',    '@hillaryclinton',    '\',    'n',    '\',
>   'nvoters',    'deserve',    'to',    'know',    'what',    'she',
>   'told',    'wall',    'street',    'and',    'big',    'pharma',
>   'beh',    '…',    "'",    ',',    "'",    'rt',    '@camaranjeri',
>   ':',    'bernie',    '❤',    '️',    '.',
>   ')'])

I understand that tok.tokenize(x) receives a tuple as the and parses the whole expression including brackets and comma which I am trying to aviod. I tried

`user_tweets.mapValues(lambda x: list(tok.tokenize(i) for i in x)))`

but get the following error :

```
Can't pickle local object 'Tokenizer.tokenize.<locals>.<lambda>'
```

How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

`pickle` can't serialize `lambda` functions. That's what the error is trying to tell you.

Try defining a function explicitly:

```
def row_tokenizer(row):
    return [tok.tokenize(x) for x in row]
```

Then passing that into your `mapValues` method call in place of the `lambda`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried explicitly defining the function before passing it into mapValues but get the same error